# p:inputText in p:dataTable not setting the value in the bean

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to implement a dataTable which contains (among other things) a column with a textInput so I can modify a string value in the bean. My problem is that the bean does not update correctly, so this is part of my code:

```xml
    <p:scrollPanel style="height:625px" mode="native">

    <p:dataTable value="#{oaBean.documentos}" var="documento"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndexVar" rowKeyVar="documentoKey" id="documentoList"
        widgetVar="myTableWidget" paginator="true" rows="50"
        emptyMessage="#{messages['norecords']}">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['documents']}" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:column style="width:1px;margin:0;padding:0;" headerText="#">
            <h:outputText value="#{rowIndexVar+1}"
                style="font-size:0.75em;margin:0;padding:0;" />
        </p:column>
        //lots of another columns
        <p:column headerText="#{messages['documento.orden']}"
              style="width:25px; text-align: center" id="columnOrden" widgetVar="columnOrden">
              <p:inputText id="ordenDocumento" value="#{documento.orden}"
              disabled="#{documento.eliminado}" style="font-size:0.9em" size="2"
              validator="floatValidator">
              </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:scrollPanel>
```

The thing is that when the control returns to the bean the value of `orden` is not updated, I always have the old value. I've also tried adding an ajax listener for the `change` event and it seems to work fine, but if I change for example, 5 rows, at least one of them maintains the old value, so my question is: is there any known problem with dataTables and textInputs? Is something wrong with my code?

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance guys.

**UPDATE**
Sorry, I've forgot to include some information. First of all, I'm working with Mojarra 2.1.5, PrimeFaces 3.4.2 and Facelets and running in Tomcat 7. Second, and probably the most important, the code presented above is included through a tab into a larger xhtml:

```
<ui:define name="body">
    <rich:panel styleClass="createFormPanel">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="margin:0 auto;width:100%;" id="principalPanel">
    <div style="height: 665px"><p:tabView id="tabs" widgetVar="tabsView" activeIndex="#{oaBean.activeTab}">
        <p:tab id="tab5" title="#{messages['oa.tab.contenido']}">
            <h:form id="formTab2">  
            <ui:include src="/pages/oa/tabContenido.xhtml" />
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView></div>
    </h:panelGroup>
    </rich:panel>
</ui:define>
```

In this case, `tabContenido.xhtml` is the page containing the data table definition. Didn't include the java code because is just a bean with getter and setter values. If you need more information just let me know.
Regards.

Comment: Please post code in SSCCE flavor. Based on the information provided so far, there are at least 3 possible causes and I can't tell which one it is. At least, most likely your model has incompatibly changed as compared to the view. For hints as to creating an SSCCE, read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Thank you @BalusC, I'll read the link and edit the post

Comment: Edited the post @BalusC, I've forgot to mention that the first code is included through a tab into another file :S

Comment: Hi @BalusC, sorry to bother you, but I still couldn't solve this, do you have any advice? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an ajax event to the column and updating the hole table, something like this:

```
            <p:column headerText="#{messages['documento.orden']}"
            style="width:25px; text-align: center" id="columnOrden">
            <p:inputText id="ordenDocumento" value="#{documento.orden}"
                disabled="#{documento.eliminado}" style="font-size:0.9em" size="2"
                validator="floatValidator">
                <p:ajax event="change" update="documentoList" />
            </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time